# Grid Layout overlaps on each other while loading images in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have created an android app that fetchs image urls from external file on server. then it fetches images on that link and displays inside a gridview.
i get those images successfully but while it loads i see the upper row of gridview overlaps on below row of gridview. i want a static sized blocks to display images inside gridview.
here is the image of my app screen i am getting .
http://s28.postimg.org/jtja4uz59/Screenshot_2014_07_01_18_39_31.png

here is the layout i am using for gridview. and gridview inside activity..

grid_layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" >

 <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

grid_layout_relative

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
         />

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher">        
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"



        android:textSize="15sp">        
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the other problem is the first block of the first row is loaded but displayed little downside compared to others inside first row. the image is in the below link.

[image]

please help me

Comment: Try to add this android:adjustViewBounds="true" properties to your ImageView.

Comment: does not make any diffrence!

Comment: I have managed to solve the overlapping problem by adjusting bigger size for progressbar and imageview! but i dont know why the first block of first row is little downward compared to others! as shown in image above! Please help me on that...

Answer (score 0):

User this resize Imageview Git : 
https://github.com/rogcg/gridview-autoresized-images-sample